# Save Rails array with outer quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to save the following array without outer quotes? Or is it possible to access the array without the outer quotes?

```
e.hours = "5:30AM", "6:00AM", "6:30AM"
# => ["5:30AM", "6:00AM", "6:30AM"] 
e.save
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.6ms)  UPDATE "brands" SET "hours" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "brands"."id" = ?  [["hours", "[\"5:30AM\", \"6:00AM\", \"6:30AM\"]"], ["updated_at", "2015-09-30 00:35:25.117927"], ["id", 1]]
   (6.8ms)  commit transaction
# => true 
e
# => #<Brand id: 1, name: "Starbucks", created_at: "2015-09-23 22:59:08", updated_at: "2015-09-30 00:35:25", hours: "[\"5:30AM\", \"6:00AM\", \"6:30AM\">
```

This is what the migration looks like:

```
add_column :brands, :hours, :string, array: true, default: []
```

When I try to access the array in the controller, it returns the array with outer quotes:

```
[1] pry(#<OrdersController>)> @delivery_hours
# => "[\"5:30AM\", \"6:00AM\", \"6:30AM\"]"
```

Comment: what exactly is `@delivery_hours`?

Comment: What database are you using? PostgreSQL? MySQL? SQLite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your order.rb file, add this:

```
serialize :hours, Array
```

Comment: I added serialize, but it still does not work. Still getting `[1] pry(#<OrdersController>)> @delivery_hours => "[\"5:15AM\", \"6:00AM\", \"6:30AM\"]"`

Comment: @Emma You'll also need to change the column to a `:text` column in order for serialize to work properly

Comment: @photoionized very nice! I forgot this.

Answer (score 2):

Rails stores array records in JSON format, so you just need to change JSON to array.

```
JSON.parse("[\"5:30AM\", \"6:00AM\", \"6:30AM\"]")
# => ["5:30AM", "6:00AM", "6:30AM"]
```

Comment: Normally you don't need to `parse` manually. ActiveRecord handles serialization automatically: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize

Comment: @thebenedict yes,  should add `serialize` method to model.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with serialize, but it still does not work. Still getting `[1] pry(#<OrdersController>)> @delivery_hours => "[\"5:15AM\", \"6:00AM\", \"6:30AM\"]"`

Comment: removed it and rolledback + migrated and restarted server. Does not work still. Am I missing something? :(

Comment: @Emma Did you reload the code in rails console? and can you show the model code to us?